# Related data field missing in view immediately after insert using Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have two related tables that I am updating via the entity framework 6 in a MVC application.

The two tables are Record and Party.  The foreign key table is Party and I am accessing a field in that table immediately after insert - Party.Name.  However, that field appears empty even though PartyId exists.

```
recordRepository.Insert(newRecord);
recordRepository.Save();

var records = recordRepository.All.Where(x => recordIds.Contains(x.RecordId));

return PartialView("_RecordIndex", records);
```

In the partial view _RecordIndex the reference to Party.Name is empty but when the screen is refreshed it then appears.

The repository code is as follows:

```
public class RecordRepository
{
    MyEntities _context;


    public RecordRepository()
    {
        _context = new MyEntities();
    }

    public void Insert(Record record)
    {
        _context.Records.Add(record);
    }    


    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<BOLRecord> All
    {
        get { return _context.Records; }
    }
    public void Dispose() 
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
...
}
```

The view snippet:

```
@model Record
@if(Model.Party != null)
{
    @Model.Party.Name
}
```

In the above Model.Party is null but Model.PartyId is not null

I recently upgraded from EntityFramework 4 to 6 so that may be related.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: where are you instantiating your dbcontext?

Comment: in the repository - i'll update the post to include this

Comment: off topic, which this repository how is the context being diposed?

Comment: the controller calls a dispose method in the repository as above

Comment: disappointingly I never discovered the answer here and ended up implementing an inefficient solution to dispose then re-init the repository